# Specifying a limit for a value in SQL when a particular value is met

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL how is it possible to set a limit for an attribute value when another condition is met?
For example, a student can borrow a max of 3 resources and staff can borrow a max of 6

```
Create Table USER_T
(   UserID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    UserType varchar (25) NOT NULL,
    No_of_Resources_Borrowed int check (No_of_Resources_Borrowed=<6)
    CONSTRAINT con_user_typ check (UserType IN ('Student','Staff'))
);
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Hint: AND/OR in constraint,

Comment: I am using Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a CONSTRAINT clause

```
Create Table USER_T
(   UserID int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    UserType varchar (25) NOT NULL,
    No_of_Resources_Borrowed int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Resources_by_type CHECK (
      No_of_Resources_Borrowed 
      <= case UserType when 'Student' then 3 when 'Staff' then 6 else 2147483647 end ),
    CONSTRAINT con_user_typ CHECK (UserType IN ('Student','Staff'))
    );
```

Comment: 2147483647 coding always raise eyebrows.

Comment: Sure I would prefer kind of INT_MAXVALUE ..

Comment: Same thing. BTW, no need for the `else`, NULL will pass!